# Nginx Caching for Rest API

Tags: rest, caching, nginx, spring-boot

I have created a Spring Boot project. I have to cache one Rest API call:

> GET localhost:8080/parts

For that I have used `nginx`. But it is not working : every time I call the API, that call is going to backend. My configuration file is given below.

**/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
http {
    include            mime.types;
    default_type       application/octet-stream;
    sendfile           on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    proxy_cache_path /var/log/oms levels=1:2 keys_zone=webcache:10m inactive=1d max_size=2000m;
    proxy_cache_min_uses 1;

    #upstream backend_server {
    # server localhost:8080;    
    #}

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location /parts {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080/parts;
            proxy_cache webcache;
        }

        #location /{
        #    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        #    proxy_cache webcache;
        #}
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

Comment: "isn't working" is not helpful - please describe the behaviour you are seeing, and what you expect to see

Comment: yes I have to cash localhost:8080/parts get api, but every time when i call the api, the call is going to backend server every time. Also the folder which i have added to store cashed file is empty

Comment: Please remove the = between server_name and localhost

Comment: tried but not working